# DataContext of DataTemplates (in ItemsControl)

Tags: wpf, windows-phone, datatemplate, datacontext, itemscontrol

I don't understand the behavior of DataContext inside a "HeaderTemplate" and a "ItemTemplate". Why do they act different? Inside "ItemTemplate" the Designer knows that the DataContext of that DataTemplate is a ViewModel and I can reference all the VM's (public) properties.

Inside "HeaderTemplate" this is not the case. The Designer/IntelliSense does not show available properties from my ViewModel. In WPF you can solve this by adding the DataType of the VM to the DataTemplate but DataType is not available in WindowsPhone (and I think also not in WinRT). The application runs fine in runtime but I want to get rid of those warnings in the Designer.

```
<phone:Pivot Title="APP TITLE" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItemViewModels}">
    <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Inside this DataTemplate the designer knows that the DataContext is of type "MenuItemViewModel". The property "Text" is known and there are no warnings. Yeeha. -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- Inside this DataTemplate it seems that the designer does not know about any DataContext. Therefore property "Title" is not known and the designer shows a warning. -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
</phone:Pivot>
```

Edit:
When I start the application both Text and Title are displayed correctly - I create three ViewModels in CodeBehind so there are three Pivots on the UI, each with Text (as Pivot Content) and Title (as Pivot Header) displayed correctly. So in Runtime the Framework knows that it has to use my ViewModel-Collection as DataContext but in DesignTime not?

Comment: `MenuItemViewModels` is what type?

Comment: MenuItemViewModels is of type ObservableCollection<MenuItemViewModel>

Comment: When the DataContext is assigned to `Pivot`?

Comment: DataContext is assigned immediately after View is initialized (via Code Behind in constructor). Also there is designtime DataContext assigned to whole UserControl. Designer still displays property "Text" in red color and "Title" in default Color for fields. So Title is found in ViewModel, Text not.